# drupal 6 site setup in local it's redirecting to production site

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am tried to setup the production site into my local system by copying the source code files and imported DB into my local system successfully.

When I tried to access the local site from browser like localhost/foldername it redirecting to production site. I want to access to my local system.

Please can any one let me know how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check in settings file if there domain of original file hard-coded somewhere.
File should be at: `sites/default/settings.php`

Also check if maybe redirection is made from `.htaccess` file located in site root folder.

If you don't find it there simply search trough all the files and database dump file and look for domain name.

Change it to your local domain name.

Comment: i replaced the site name in sql file but site is loading without them. just plain text is displaying.